# NSDateFormatter returns nil sometimes

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I created a NSDateFormatter but sometimes it creates an NSDate out of a given string sometimes it doesn't on the same device (Simulator).

This is my code:

```
NSString *lastModifiedString = [metaData objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *onlineModDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastModifiedString];
```

For Example for the string
"Fri, 09 Jan 2015 15:08:01 GMT" it returns nil but for "Fri, 12 Dec 2014 09:15:52 GMT" it returns the right NSDate.

I tried to add parenthesis to the dateformat and I tried to set locale to "en_US_POSIX" and i tried a little z instead of a big one but neither of it worked.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a guess:  It parses 12:59:59 OK, but fails on 13:00:00.  What's different between those two?

Comment: Bookmark this link: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: the problem is `hh`, because is indicates hour in a 12 hour format. Hence 15 is not valid. Use `HH`, which is used for 24 hour format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDateFormatter follows the [Unicode standard for date and time patterns.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) Use 'H' for the hour on a 24-hour clock:

So in your code, the correct way should be:

```
NSString *lastModifiedString = [metaData objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *onlineModDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastModifiedString];
```